# How to have a directive apply to only a certain type of element content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to create a directive that only matches `<input type="password"`.

Any time compile finds this type of input, I want my directive to apply. I don't want to add anything to the element (an extra class or attribute).

Is this possible? How do I do it?

**SOLUTION:**

For posterity's sake, I'm including my [solution](http://codepen.io/tmorrow-hyphensolutions/pen/QjvKdZ):

```js
angular.module('controls', [])

.directive('type',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function(element, attributes) {
        if (element.prop('nodeName') === 'INPUT' && attributes.type === 'password') {
          return function link(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
            element.on('keypress', function(event) {
              var s = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
              if (s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !event.shiftKey) {
                element.addClass('capslock');
              } else {
                element.removeClass('capslock');
              }
            });
          };
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.capslock {
  background: #fff url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat right -10px center;
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  background-position: right 5px center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='controls'>
  Type into second box with caps on or off and see what happens!
  <br/>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="password" id="search-box" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="text search" />
  <p>{{searchString}}</p>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Problem is, Angular already provides an `<input>` directive. I suppose you could add a `type` attribute directive and check the element type in the `pre` link function

Comment: Yeah, that or compile on the fly all matching element, like with jq `$('input[type="password"]').each( /* add directive attribute and $compile it */ )` but that's a bad idea anyway, why would you do that instead of writting a directive?

Comment: `$compile($('input[type="password"]').attr('mydirective',true))(scope)`

Comment: In Angular 2, this is easy. In Angular 1, not so easy.

Comment: @frosty, it's latest version (new development). Yeehaw!

Comment: If that is the case, then directives in Angular 2 are simply CSS selectors. So you can use the same selector as you would in CSS to target your element. So input[type="password"] will get it.

Comment: @frosty, latest *stable* version. sorry. darn. maybe when it comes out we can switch and i save an if statement. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a directive for `type` attributes and only executing the linking functions if the element is `<input>` and `type` is *"password"*

```
.directive('type', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            if (tElement.prop('nodeName') === 'INPUT' && tAttrs.type === 'password') {
                return function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    // etc
                };
            }
        }
    };
})
```

Plunker demo where the directive adds the *"red"* class to the element ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/EurHOzKiloE6B0QQSwAY?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Phil! I can see how this would work. I'll give it a show and let you know! I'm writing a CAPS LOCK icon to show up in the password box. Pretty cool if I can get it working.

Comment: Check out my edit to my question. I thank you for what you were able to help me do, and it is pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

I would place a transclude directive on `<body>` and then add the directives before the transclude was compiled.

```
angular.directive('body',function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope,el,attr,ctrl,transcludeFn) {
             transcludeFn(function(cloned){
                 cloned.find('input[type="password"]').attr('newDirective',true);
                 el.append(cloned);
             });
        }
     }
}
```

I haven't tested the above, but it would be something like that.

Comment: Note that this would require jQuery (jqLite does not support anything other than element type selectors)

Comment: I'm so use to using jquery. I think this might work instead if you don't have jquery. `cloned.querySelector('input[type="password"]').setAttribute('newDirective',true);`

Comment: you might have to use `angular.forEach` but you get the idea.